# Swift 4 perform segue from UITableView and pass data

Tags: ios, swift

I have 1 UITableViewController and 1 UIViewController. Inside my UITableViewController I have this didSelectRowAt method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PDFIdentifier", sender: nil)

}
```

which runs this code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFFile") as! PDFFileController

        viewController.data = self.file

        viewController.fileName = self.fileName

    }
```

This does present modally the UIViewController PDFFileController and when I put a breakpoint inside the present method viewController.data and viewController.fileName is being populated. When It gets over the PDFFileController those values are empty. Why are they empty and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a segue but to present

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFFile") as! PDFFileController

   viewController.data = self.file

   viewController.fileName = self.fileName

   self.present(viewController,animated:true)
}
```

---

**Or** if you want to keep the segue modal properties

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let viewController = segue.destination as! PDFFileController

    viewController.data = self.file

    viewController.fileName = self.fileName

}
```

**never** instantiate a vc inside `prepareForSegue` as it will be a new instance on  the fly and the real destination vc won't get it's data

[image]

Comment: Sweet, I like answer number 2 the best. I just have one question. My UITableViewController is inside a Navigation controller, using answer number 2 (the one with the prepare) can I push to a navigation controller?

Comment: Do you want to modally present it over context or push it ??? look to segue options